# Show diff between two files in specific format

Tags: bash, diff

here is the question: I have two files:

file1:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

file2:

```
bbb
ddd
```

HOW TO USE DIFF TO GET THIS OUTPUT (only differences)

```
aaa
ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is records unique to file1, then :

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
aaa
ccc
```